# Does SFML render it's graphics using OpenGL internally?

Tags: c++, opengl, sdl, windows, sfml

By that, I mean that SFML has an abstraction for OpenGL? Sort of like SDL's blit functions, but using OpenGL internally?

"Yes SFML uses OpenGL for all the graphical stuff. "

Received this comment in an earlier question, which sort of baffled me since I find nothing about it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it does use OpenGL for some operations. You can get the full list from the [source code](http://www.sfml-dev.org/download.php). The major uses are, as of SFML 1.6:

- `RenderTarget.cpp`: set up render targets, clear screen, set matrix mode *etc*.
- `PostFX.cpp`: postprocess manager
- `Image.cpp` and `Sprite.cpp`: texture and sprite handling
- `String.cpp`: text writing

In the upcoming SFML 2.0, some of this is slightly modified because of the support for the fully programmable pipeline. For instance, `Sprite.cpp` no longer uses OpenGL directly, and instead fills vertex buffers for rendering by `RenderTarget.cpp` instead.

It is possible to use SFML without the application having knowledge of OpenGL, but its features will be pretty limited (basic sprite and text rendering, some post-process effects). The more common use case is to use SFML to create a GL context.

Comment: This question of mine came up when I was wondering how to use OpenGL in SDL, since using SDL's blitSurface quickly slowed my program enough to have to use full CPU. So I thought of using OpenGL with SDL to delegate the drawing on the graphic card and free my CPU.

Comment: Woops, pressed enter ~ So basically, you're saying SFML does what I was aiming at with SDL + OpenGL?

Comment: It does slightly more; SDL really leaves you with only the GL context, whereas SFML provides utility functions for loading images into textures, shader creation, postprocess effects, pushing/popping GL states… It’s not a replacement for a full rendering engine, but it does make your life easier if you’re rolling your own simple GL code.

Comment: So, if I "port" my SDL, software rendered game, to SFML, I'll be using graphic card and be very light on the CPU? Just to be sure. But I'll accept it asap, you've done enough

Comment: Oh and as a final question, is SFML 2.0 stable enough to use? I'm reading some very good things about it!

Comment: SFML 2.0 is stable. It will be officially released when the official tutorials are all written by the dev. (check the [roadmap](https://github.com/LaurentGomila/SFML/issues/milestones), it's the only thing remaining). So yes, use 2.0.

Comment: Ok, that conclues the question! A big thank you to everyone!